# Error loading vectors in fasttext/torchtext

Tags: python, pytorch, fasttext

I get the following error:

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

When running this:

```
class FastText(Vectors):

    url_base = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki.{}.vec'

    def __init__(self, language="en", **kwargs):
        url = self.url_base.format(language)
        name = os.path.basename(url)
        super(FastText, self).__init__(name, url=url, **kwargs)
```

How can I fix it?

Changing the url and that did not work

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 403 "Forbidden" error means that the server to which you've sent your request is refusing to let you access that URL, perhaps because it's not open to the public, or requires extra authentication.

If I try the URL `https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki.en.vec` from a web-browser, I get the same error. So this isn't really an issue with your code, or `python`, or `pytorch`, or `fasttext`. You've just got an improper expectation that the given URL will return what you wnat it to.

What reference, or entity, made you think `https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki.en.vec` would give you what you need? You may need to follow-up with whoever recommended that URL, and let them know their recommendation does not work, or find an alternate source.

Only if an URL works for you in your browser should you expect it will also work in your code, with no extra authentication steps. And, it still might break for other reasons, like the system where your code is running having a disfavored network IP-address – so before supplying such an URL to configure a custom subclass of `Vectors`, you might run some code from that same system to verify the URL loads at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The code I am trying to run is from the authors of a paper from 2019. The url was already there.

Comment: You're welcome! If the paper authors maintain an up-to-date guide beyond the original paper (which is rare), they could be advised to supply a new URL, or you'll just want to find an URL with the same vectors, or vectors of similar value for your project. And you may want to find the vectors once, saving them locally – then adapt the code to reuse that known-good local copy, rather than re-fetching from a remote URL repeatedly (which could break whenver that URL goes bad). Some of the offerings at <https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html> might be applicable. Good luck!